# Arduino: load variables with values read from SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, sd-card, data-type, float

I am having a bit of trouble loading values stored on an SD card and assigning them to variables within my program. I can achieve this as one big block of data, but would much prefer them to be saved to variables whilst in a loop or some other process.

My txt file has the following 6 ints & floats values, which are displayed vertically in the file:

2
0.003200
312
1
0.720000
8

Each of these values I want assigned to variables data1,....2,3,4,5,6. Unfortunately, the code I use below will never achieve this, but I am clueless as to any theory to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_READ);
    if (myFile) {
    while (myFile.available()) {
        data = myFile.read();
    }
myFile.close();
}
else {
    Serial.println("Read Error");
}
```

Comment: These are values that change if anyone's thinking why don't I just hard code it instead.

Comment: Putting all such variables in a `struct` could be a good choice, as you can then copy the contents of the struct as raw data to/from the card (though getting at it from another system like a PC would require knowledge of how the Arduino compiler packs structs).  But you can also read the variables one by one; the big problem at present is that your code doesn't *have* any variables that it even *attempts* to load from the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File implements [Stream](http://arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream) just like Serial. so you can use parseInt and parseFloat

```
int n = File.parseInt();
float x = File.parseFloat();
Serial.println(n);
Serial.println(x, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just had a search for readByteUntil, it sounds like it could be what I'm looking for, but how would this be implemented into my code. How would I distinguish which goes where?

Comment: Would I list the parseInts and floats according to the order within my list? And would I put this within the 'available()' method? Thanks.

Comment: in your case you do not need readBytesUntil. only parse the numbers like in the code snippet in my answer. parseInt and parseFloat skips the spaces.

Comment: myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_READ);
    if (myFile) {
        while (myFile.available()) {
            km = myFile.parseInt();
            kmTemp = myFile.parseFloat();
            kmrevs = myFile.parseInt();
            miles = myFile.parseInt();
            milesTemp = myFile.parseFloat();
            milesrevs = myFile.parseInt();
            
            Serial.println(km);
            ........other printlns()
            }
        myFile.close();
        }
    else {
        Serial.println("Read Error");
    }

Comment: Is that what you mean. I could only squeeze in so many characters in this comment.

Comment: yes. are there more lines? then while (available()) is ok

Comment: The parse functions are only appropriate if you store the values as text.  If they are something like files created by a text editor on a PC that could indeed be appropriate.  OTOH if they are saved from one Arduino session to another, a direct binary copy of how the values would be stored in Arduino RAM may be more fitting.

Comment: No there is not more lines, the same data is replaced as and when required.