# Arduino variables loaded from SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, sd-card, variables, data-type

I am trying to load some variables from an SD card on the start up of my arduino Uno. I have been given some advice but am unable to communicate at the same hours. Using this advice, I have the following edited code, but it doesn't work and I believe that it's my implementation that is the problem. All help would be greatly appreciated.

```
myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_READ);
    if (myFile) {
        while (myFile.available()) {
            myFile.read();

            km = myFile.parseInt();
            kmTemp = myFile.parseFloat();
            kmrevs = myFile.parseInt();
            miles = myFile.parseInt();
            milesTemp = myFile.parseFloat();
            milesrevs = myFile.parseInt();

            }
        myFile.close();
        }
    else {
        Serial.println("Read Error");
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Describe further. And what is actually written in the file you want to read?

Comment: The program gathers/calculates 6 pieces of data which is then saved to a text file on an SD card. The text file displays the 6 pieces of data in a vertical list. On power up of the arduino, I am trying to make the program read these 6 bits of data, assigning the values to 6 different variables before the program hits the loop (this script is within setup() if that eliminates a question).

Comment: When ran and then restarted the data output is at the programs defaults of '0' & '0.000000' where floats apply....not the data that is saved on the disk.

Comment: You still have not listed the file from your SDCard.  Make sure you are using a plain text editor for this.  For example, Microsoft Word or Adobe Framemaker would add an unbelievable amount of overhead that would confuse the parsing library.

Comment: `what is actually written in the file you want to read?` please answer this question.

Comment: After the parseInt, the next character will be you delimiter. For example a comma (`,`). The next time you call parseInt, it will see the comma, and return 0. Try putting a `myFile.read();` between each parseInt/parseFloat.

Comment: myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    if (myFile) {
        myFile.println(km);
        myFile.println(kmTemp, 6);
        myFile.println(kmrevs);
        myFile.println(miles);
        myFile.println(milesTemp, 6);
        myFile.println(milesrevs);
        myFile.close();
    }
    else {
        // SD SAVE ERROR
        Serial.println("Save Error");
    }

Comment: That is how I save it. The test.txt file contains the following example numbers : 1, 0.001600, 12, 0, 0.072000, 0. These are listed vertically in the text file using println() in the save method just posted.

Comment: Gerben - I tried the myFile.read() which hasn't done anything different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you [previous question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/arduino-load-variables-with-values-read-from-sd-card), where I answered, you had no commas or new-lines in the example file content. the parseInt and parseFloat ignores only spaces by default.

remove the commas or read them or ignore them with parseInt parameter SKIP_ALL

```
km = myFile.parseInt(SKIP_ALL);
```

Comment: Hi there is no commas, it's just in the comments section, whenever I press enter it posts the message instead of starts a new line....so I used commas to seperate the different data.

Comment: Hi Juraj. I have to admit, I have never analysed anything as much as your two answers. I feel that my bank holiday was no longer wasted as I have finally worked out what you meant. All is rolling amazingly now and it's just what I wanted. Thank you.